# Expression calculation using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a table with one span tag with some value and 6 inputs with ID's generated automatically, where value updated from database, that can be changed.

```
<td><span id="Day${c.id}">/*generated automatically*/</span></td>
<td><input class="inp${c.id}" name="b1-${c.id}" id="b1${c.id}" value="${c.exp?.b1}" type="text"/></td>
<td><input class="inp${c.id}" name="b2-${c.id}" id="b2-${c.id}" value="${c.exp?.b2}" type="text"/></td>
<td><input class="inp${c.id}" name="b3-${c.id}" id="b3-${c.id}" value="${c.exp?.b3}" type="text"/></td>
<td><input class="inp${c.id}" name="b4-${c.id}" id="b4-${c.id}" value="${c.exp?.b4}" type="text"/></td>
<td><input class="inp${c.id}" name="b5-${c.id}" id="b5-${c.id}" value="${c.exp?.b5}" type="text"/></td>
<td><input class="inp${c.id}" name="b6-${c.id}" id="b6-${c.id}" value="${c.exp?.b6}" type="text"/></td>
<td><span id="Total${c.id}">0</span></td>
```

I need to realtime calculate onKeyUp expression like this:

`total = span*(input1*(input2+input3)+input4+input5+input6)`

Comment: It will be better if you post the rendered markup here.

Answer (score 0):

try following,

```
$('table').find('input').each(function()
{
    //  this.do_your_own_thing here....
    // read jquery doc to see all options
})
```

Answer (score 0):

[Edited for the very specific requirement of OP]

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[id^="inp"]').keyup(function(){
        var total = 0;
        var temp = 0;
        $('input[id^="inp"]').each(function(i){
            if(i==0)
                total = $(this).val();
            else if(i==1)
                temp = $(this).val();
            else if(i==2)
                total = total*(temp+$(this).val());
            else
                total += $(this).val();
        });

        total *= $('span[id^="Day"]').val();
        $('span[id^="Total"]').val(total);
    });
});
```

Comment: I think you're missing the requirements for multiplication.

Comment: I need expression like this: total = span*(input1*(input2+input3)+input4+input5+input6)

Comment: will there always be 6 inputs?

Comment: i have edited the answer for your specific requirement. Does it help?

Comment: what is the result it's giving? Did you insert the code within a keyup event handler?

Comment: The code needs a firing point. It can't run by itself. when exactly do you want the code to run? Is there a 'calculate' button or anything?

Comment: There is no calculate button. I need that it works on a keypress

Comment: I need that it works when I put value in inputs. It must calcuated autamtically in realtime

Comment: you are not giving me any feedback (logs, console output, what is happening?) to work with. Sorry.